# How to dynamic infer generic typing in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

### Description

Let's say i have an interface `A`, `A` inferface have three sub inferface 'X', 'Y', 'Z', They are all generic.

```js
interface A<T>{}

interface X<T> extends A<T>{
  [x_property: string]: any
}

interface Y<T> extends A<T>{
  [y_property: string]: any
}

interface Z<T> extends A<T>{
  [z_property: string]: any
}

// -------------------------

const obj: Y<...> = {...}
```

### Problem

How can i infer the type of `obj`, suppose there are many sub-inferfaces in the `A` interface.

Equivalent to `type E<T> = T extends (infer U)<any> ? U : never`

I don't know how to describe this behavior

### Purpose

```js
const obj: Y<...> = {...}
type ObjType = typeof obj;
// invalid syntax, the inferred `U` is extends `A`
type Generic = ObjType extends (infer U)<any> ? U : never
// valid syntax
type Arguments = ObjType extends A<infer U> ? U : never;
type NewArguments = {...}
const newObj: Generic<Arguments & NewArguments> = {
    ...obj, ...(...) as NewArguments
}
```

Comment: Please add to your question the type U are expect. I don't understand the question

Comment: where is the `T` type argument being used?. All of your "sub-interfaces" seem identical.

Comment: @captain-yossarian `U` is inferred, similar to `type E<T> = T extends AnyGeneric<U> ? U : never`

Comment: @Chase `T` type argument is not used, i just want to infer what generic type `Y` is in  `const obj: Y<...> = {...}`

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible. You can either infer generic if it is a type of function arguments or return type